# Very occasional fatal PHP error, "couldn't execute" autoload function

Tags: php

I have no idea how to go about solving this very occasional funny state that PHP gets into. So any ideas whatsoever will be appreciated.

Maybe 3 or 4 times in the past year, my site will start returning 500 errors, and the logs show:

PHP Fatal error:  Couldn't execute method dw__autoload in Unknown on line 0

dw__autoload is registered with spl_autoload_register. When I restart apache the problem is gone and I forget about it for several months. I am running APC, php 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10 on ubuntu 10.04.3. I realize there is not much to go on here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [source code from the point of this error](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_interfaces.c#105), I'd risk (psychic debugging since you have no more details) to say this happens because the autoload is being called with already an exception thrown.

That said, I can't see exactly how this can happen. The current exception is cleared both before calling the autoloader and after calling each SPL autoloader function. I don't think we ever can get to a conclusion without a script that reproduces this problem. The full set of possibilities is:

- The execution was already shut down
- There's a current exception
- The function is no longer valid (I see that happening only due to a bug in PHP, but anyway it's not likely because it almost certainly would generate a warning before)
- The autoloader function requires a reference (again, this would also generate a warning before, and your autoloader would never work anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's hard for me to give more details... I suppose I am hoping there is someone out there who has had the exact same problem. Is "Unknown on line 0" a clue, or the fact we use APC? As I've already missed the opportunity to debug on this occasion, any suggestions on what I might do the next time this happens?

Comment: @Ben You can compile PHP with debug symbols and next time it happens attach gdb to it and try to figure out what's happening. Anyway, this is likely a bug in APC.